# What does the notation $D$ mean here?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, notation

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

So what does the notation $D$ mean in the definition of relative entropy?

I try to explain the $D$ as $\nabla_{(\rho,u)}$, but it seems not right.

The article is "EXISTENCE AND UNIQUENESS OF GLOBAL STRONG SOLUTIONS FOR ONE-DIMENSIONAL COMPRESSIBLE NAVIER–STOKES EQUATIONS"

DOI. 10.1137/060658199

Answer (score 0):

[image: clerical error]

There is a clerical error. There should be a $\frac{1}{2}$

$D$ means $\nabla_{(\rho,m)}$